# How to narrow down the list of CSS properties in autocomplete of Firefox Developer Tools or Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, firebug, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

We write CSS properties a lot. That's why autocomplete comes in handy. But it's a little frustrating when I press `v` hoping for `vertical-align` and it comes out `vector-effect` or `d` hoping for `display` and it comes out `direction` etc.

I would like to limit this list of properties in Firefox (also Firefox Developer Edition) or Firebug to only those I really use. Is there such possiblity? Or maybe you could propose another tool which includes this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firebug already tries to be smart and does complete `d` to `display`. In case you type `v` it completes to `visibility`. The code for this can be found here:

https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/77b0d5620227852757b8a9c1d6167a44f7210172/extension/content/firebug/css/autoCompleter.js#L32

So if you want to change these defaults, you need to change them within Firebug's source code and build it by your own.

The built-in DevTools currently (Firefox 33.1.1) don't have such logic and simply display the first option in alphabetical order. To get that logic improved you should file an enhancement request for them.